# Highlight top of a JavaFX TableRow with css

Tags: css, javafx-8

I'm trying to figure out the CSS for highlighting the top of a TableRow. I'm using this for reordering rows so that anyone reordering them can tell where it will be inserted. Currently I've only been able to draw a rectangle around the row, but I just want the top line of that rectangle.

```
.table-row-cell.drag {
    -fx-focus-color: #00a9d3;
    -fx-faint-focus-color: #00a9d322;

    -fx-highlight-fill: -fx-accent;
    -fx-background-color:
        -fx-focus-color,
        -fx-control-inner-background,
        -fx-faint-focus-color,
        linear-gradient(from 0px 0px to 0px 5px, derive(-fx-control-inner-background, -9%), -fx-control-inner-background);
    -fx-background-insets: -0.2, 1, -1.4, 3;
    -fx-background-radius: 3, 2, 4, 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could specify different `-fx-background-insets` for the sides. If one color should only appear on one side, the insets of the next color match the insets for the mark color except for the side that should be colored.

Furthermore I recommend using `PseudoClass` instead of a style class, since this way you don't need to make sure to not add a class multiple times.

```
final PseudoClass mark = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("mark");

...

boolean marked = ...
row.pseudoClassStateChanged(mark, marked);
```

The following CSS is a bit simplified, but it should demonstrate the approach:

```css
.table-row-cell:mark {
    -fx-background-color: -fx-table-cell-border-color, red, -fx-background;

    /* show red highlight of size 2 at the top */
    -fx-background-insets: 0, 0 0 1 0, 2 0 1 0;
}
```